# What is the R equivalent for Python's .cat.codes, which converts categorical variable to integer levels?

Tags: r, numeric, categorical-data, r-factor

In python, you can generate a categorical code for a variable using .cat.code e.g.

```
df['col3'] = df['col3'].astype('category').cat.code
```

How do you do this in R ?

Comment: If I understand `.cat.code` correctly, you want the numeric representation of the categories. If this is your factor: `a <- factor(c("good", "bad", "good", "bad", "terrible"))` then to get the numbers you can do this: as.numeric(labels(a))[a]

Comment: @Amar Yes, can you write that as an answer and I will accept ir :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleshing this out a bit further for @Sid29:

The python method function `.cat.code` extracts the numeric representation of the levels of a factor. The equivalent in R is:

```
a <- factor(c("good", "bad", "good", "bad", "terrible"))

as.numeric(a)
[1] 2 1 2 1 3
```

Note that `.cat.code` will represent `NA` (or `NaN` same thing) as `-1` while the above solution in R still preservers `NA` and output will be simply `NA`.

Edit: `as.numeric(a)` is better. There's discussion on the use of `labels` function inside `as.numeric` function. See the warning in `?factor`:

> In particular, as.numeric applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion. To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f)).
>
> There are some anomalies associated with factors that have NA as a level. It is suggested to use them sparingly, e.g., only for tabulation purposes.

If you have an `NA` value, it will coerce all values to `NA`, thus the reason for using `labels`. Interestingly, `c(a)` works (see @42 answer below).

Comment: Why `as.numeric(labels(a))[a]`? Doesn't `as.numeric(a)` do the same thing more simply?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is clearer to do the following:

```
# if you want numeric code for every value
a <- factor(c("good", "bad", "good", "bad", "terrible"))
as.integer(a)
# 2 1 2 1 3


# unique labels and the values for them
setNames(levels(a), seq_along(levels(a)))
#    1          2          3 
# "bad"     "good" "terrible"
```

Comment: That's a bit weird. Setting names to levels should not be necessary or clarify the situation. Furthermore it's not clear if you understand that did nothing to the `a` object.

Comment: @42- was more of a way to say here are the underlying numeric codes for the values.  Got a better way to show them together?

Comment: Why not just use `levels(a)` if that was what you wanted to show?

Comment: But the point is to show that AND the number behind it, which for R will always be sequential - so its more handholding if anything.

Comment: Maybe it helps for Python users but it looks weird for this R user. I think the other answer that used `labels()` seemed clearer.

Comment: The previous answer is redundant as far as i can tell, can be done with `as.integer(a)`

Comment: Or (curiously) even `c(a)`. Turns out that in R there is no `c.factor` and using `c` has the same effect as does `as.vector`  or as you offered as does `as.integer`.

Comment: Factors are flipping weird.